# Content Editor webpart sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

when i was insert two content editor web parts  in same page with some javascript code its shows only one cwpt result in sharepoint 2013.When i was delete one cewp shows the second content editor webpart details.Please tell me the reason.

Comment: Try adding those two web part in a other page

Comment: already i done like that i was facing same problem to that page also.in that case also shows either contenteditor web part 1/cewp2 showing

Comment: What are the web part? I mean what they do? Do they work in separate page?

Comment: one is faq accordion jquery style for sharepoint list  using content editor webpart.another is contact information with customization style getting data from sharepoint list dynamically using content editor webpart.

Comment: Do they work separately? I mean in different page?

Comment: are you getting any console error? It seems, there is a conflict between two web parts

Comment: nothing.in separately pages  it shows output.

Comment: Sorry dude. Then I have no solution unless you show your web part code. If you are using any open source code, then give me the link!

Comment: There might be an issue with your code. Don't forget the options BaseViewID and ListTemplateType.

Comment: k.Any way thanks for chart with me.i have one question please tell me the mailto tag in cewp getting mail items  dyanamically

Comment: it would be better if you share your code. Maybe you have missed something in there

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you have one page with two webparts and want to have different content edit parts on same page.

I had similar problem solving this and I found solution here:

```
http://blog.navantis.com/create-a-custom-page-layout-in-sharepoint-2013/
```

On that page you can create new page layout that will have as many content parts you want/need with different entries.
So instead of single line of text choose multiple line of text (rich content).